# Unable to install MvcMailer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, package-managers, mvcmailer

I tried intalling Mvc Mailer by entering the command "Install-Package MvcMailer" in the Package Manager Console,  but I'm getting the following error message:

```
Successfully installed 'MvcMailer 1.1'.
Successfully added 'MvcMailer 1.1' to MatchesHorsConcours.
Install-Package : The term 'Set-DefaultScaffolder' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name
, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  MvcMailer
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Well, in fact, it istalls MvcMailer, but something goes wrong during the configuration I guess.

I already have these two packages installed:

T4Scaffolding 1.0.2

MvcScaffolding 1.0.2

Answer (score 0):

I've also been using MVC mailer and encountered the same error.
I've fixed the issue by using the latest packages of T4Scaffolding and EntityFramework.

Go to your project (in your case MatchesHorsConcours) and start the [PackageManager console](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console) (MatchesHorsConcours should be selected in the Default project dropdown of the PackageManager console).

Remove MVC mailer and its dependencies:

```
uninstall-package mvcmailer -RemoveDependencies
```

Install the latest EntityFramework package

```
install-package EntityFramework
```

Install the latest T4Scaffolding package

```
install-package T4Scaffolding
```

Now install MVCMailer

```
install-package MvcMailer
```

This should do the trick - let me know if you still encounter problems after doing this.