# Error in "using Mvc.Mailer;"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvcmailer

I am trying to use `MvcMailer` for sending e-mail in my MVC3 Application.

I have successfully installed the package `MvcMailer`.

Used Reference [Unable to install MvcMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123688/unable-to-install-mvcmailer) and followed the steps

But there is error while using it. 
`using Mvc.Mailer;`
`The type or namespace name 'MailerBase' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I am mentioning error as comment in below code.

```
using Mvc.Mailer;  //The type or namespace name 'Mvc' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

namespace MvcApplicationMvcMailer.Mailers
{ 
    public class UserMailer : MailerBase, IUserMailer   //The type or namespace name 'MailerBase' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    {
        public UserMailer()
        {
            MasterName="_Layout";
        }

        public virtual MvcMailMessage Welcome()
        {
            //ViewBag.Data = someObject;
            return Populate(x =>
            {
                x.Subject = "Welcome";
                x.ViewName = "Welcome";
                x.To.Add("some-email@example.com");
            });
        }

        public virtual MvcMailMessage GoodBye()
        {
            //ViewBag.Data = someObject;
            return Populate(x =>
            {
                x.Subject = "GoodBye";
                x.ViewName = "GoodBye";
                x.To.Add("some-email@example.com");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. I needed to Install MvcMailer3. For MVC3 applications only.

Got Solution from these link 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcMailer
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcMailer3/

Answer (score 5):

The package and version of MvcMailer needed depends on **both** the the **MVC** and the **.NET** version you are using:

**ASP.NET MVC3**

```
Install-Package MvcMailer3
```

**ASP.NET MVC4 with .NET 4**

```
Install-Package MvcMailer -Version 4.0
```

**ASP.NET MVC4 with .NET 4.5**

```
Install-Package MvcMailer
```

This will likely change again when MVC5 and .NET 5 come out.