# Error in MvcMailer.dll

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvcmailer

I am trying to use `MvcMailer` for sending e-mail in my MVC3 Application.

I have successfully installed the package `MvcMailer`.

Used [Unable to install MvcMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123688/unable-to-install-mvcmailer) as reference and followed the steps.

But it was not showing in References list so I explicitly added `Mvc.Mailer.dll`.

Now it is showing Error `Assembly 'Mvc.Mailer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'`

What should I do now? Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. I needed to Install MvcMailer3. For MVC3 applications only.

Got Solution from these link 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcMailer
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcMailer3/